# Cassandra retrieving data using a time range from unixtimestampof()

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am new to Cassandra and have created a table in Cassandra as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE HAS.HASDDDB (
    Current float,
    Time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (Current, Time)
);
```

An application is inserting data to the table as follows :

```
INSERT INTO HAS.HASDDDB ( Current, Time )
VALUES ( 0.01, Dateof ( NOW ( ) ) );
```

I need to sum all the Current values for the last hour. In MYSQL i could do it like this :

```
select sum(Current) from DDDB where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Time)<=3600
```

I understand that cassandra does not support aggregate functions such as SUM. Will it be possible to achieve the same effect using a counter as i have read in some posts? If not how can i do this in cassandra?

I am also have trouble retrieving data based on a time range for example return all records from the last hour or day till now. In Cassandra how can i execute a statement like

```
SELECT * FROM HASDDDB
WHERE current = 0.00 and Time > unixTimestampof ( now ( ) -3600)  AND Time < unixTimestampof ( now ( ) );
```

which is giving me an error .I want to get the results for example till now from the last hour just like in MYSQL.

I have tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103004/cassandra-time-based-query) but it does not help.

Comment: `which is giving me an error` => Which error?

Comment: InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unable to coerce 'current unix timestamp ' to a  formatted date (long)"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately basic functions like sum and average aren't built into Cassandra yet, but a new feature in Cassandra 2.2 and later is the ability to define aggregate functions like sum.  So with a little effort you can create your own sum function that will run on the coordinator node.  See some examples of creating aggregate functions [here](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2015/05/cassandra-aggregates-min-max-avg-group.html).

If you want to sum your data by hour, it would be easier to have "hour" as a partition key and then you would sum everything in the partition without needing a range query.

Using "current" as the partition key doesn't make much sense since all the rows in the partition would have the same current value and then you might as well just get count(*) and multiply it by the current value to get the sum.

To query by timestamp you would usually use this format:

```
ts >= '2015-08-01 18:00:00' and ts < '2015-08-01 19:00:00
```

Comment: I actually wanted to query by hour,by day,by week and by month. So in this regards should i make hour as a partition key and retrieve the most recent 24 records for example for the whole day? I am writing the application in c++. To insert hourly data will i need some c++ function to generate the timestamp and then parse the string or should i use the unixtimestampof() function by cassandra instead?

Comment: Depends how much data you expect to store.  If it's not a huge amount of data you could partition by week and then do range queries within the week.  If that would be too much data for one partition, you could partition by day and query each day separately.  When you insert the data you can use dateof ( now( ) ) in CQL.  When you query you would use the date format shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Lets say i partition by day. How can i extract the day field when using dateof(now()) function in cassandra? dateof(now()) will only return the current timestamp in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. How can i extract the DD field?

Comment: I think in C++ a Cassandra timestamp field is returned as type cass_int64_t, which is probably an epoch time in ms.  Within C++ there should be library functions you can call to convert an epoch time to whatever format you need so that you can extract the day.